# How to move cursor back to the first line in C?

Tags: c, cursor, line

I am new to C and this is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printCard(char name, char symbol);

int main()
{
    printCard('J','*');
    printCard('K','&');  
}
void printCard(char name, char symbol)
{
    printf("-------------\n");
    printf("| %c         |\n",name);
    printf("| %c         |\n",symbol);
    printf("|           |\n");
    printf("|           |\n");
    printf("|           |\n");
    printf("|         %c |\n",symbol);
    printf("|         %c |\n",name);
    printf("-------------\n");
}
```

This is the output that I am getting.

[image]

Is there a way to get that second card to appear beside the first?
Thanks

Comment: What happens if you do: `printf("| %c         | | %c         |\n",name,name2);` ?

Comment: You can't move backwards in the output stream using the standard C features. There are dedicated libraries, like `ncurses` for developing textual UIs capable of it.

Comment: @this Sorry for not telling clearly. I want to print more cards like this, so I want to automate it so that I dont have to retype everything. It will only work for two cards I guess. I want to print more cards later on without messing up the function or without having to type 1000s of printf statements based on the number of cards that I print. Any ideas?

Comment: There's nothing in standard C to move the cursor around... output is just sequential.  Depending on the platform you're on, you can use a suitable library like curses, or print terminal control codes directly (exactly what they are depends on the system), or you can simply print some blank lines and reprint everything the way you want it.

Comment: Just from your screenshot, it looks like you're using Windows. If that's the case, you might want to look into  [SetConsoleCursorPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686025%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [WriteConsoleOutputCharacter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687410%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You could keep a 2D array of `char` with your output in it, so you can modify just by setting the char at the coordinates you want... then print the array to display your new output.  Just remember the null terminators (or print with the length specified).

Comment: Standard C doesn't supports this. It's platform dependent.

Comment: @PCLuddite Thanks a lot man. SetConsoleCursorPosition was the exact kind of thing that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the function that worked for me.

```
void gotoXY(int x, int y)
{

 COORD coord;

 coord.X = x;

 coord.Y = y;

 SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);

}
```

Thanks @PCLuddite for pointing me to check setConsoleCursorPosition which helped me find this above function online. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 3):

If your terminal supports them, these terminal escape codes could be use to position the cursor.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printCard( int col, char name, char symbol);

int main()
{
    printf ( "\033[2J");//clear screen
    printCard( 0, 'J','*');
    printCard( 1, 'K','&');
    return 0;
}
void printCard(int col, char name, char symbol)
{
    printf ( "\033[1;%dH", col * 14);//move cursor line 1
    printf("-------------\n");
    printf ( "\033[2;%dH", col * 14);//move cursor line 2
    printf("| %c         |\n",name);
    printf ( "\033[3;%dH", col * 14);//move cursor line 3
    printf("| %c         |\n",symbol);
    printf ( "\033[4;%dH", col * 14);//move cursor line 4
    printf("|           |\n");
    printf ( "\033[5;%dH", col * 14);//move cursor line 5
    printf("|           |\n");
    printf ( "\033[6;%dH", col * 14);//move cursor line 6
    printf("|           |\n");
    printf ( "\033[7;%dH", col * 14);//move cursor line 7
    printf("|         %c |\n",symbol);
    printf ( "\033[8;%dH", col * 14);//move cursor line 8
    printf("|         %c |\n",name);
    printf ( "\033[9;%dH", col * 14);//move cursor line 9
    printf("-------------\n");
}
```

Comment: This assumes the OP's terminal supports ANSI escape sequences. Some terminals don't (i.e. Win32 console).

Comment: I just tried this on Windows 10, and it worked. Please do not downvote the above comment since it may be true for earlier versions of Windows, and some places do indeed use legacy software