# C program to change x and y values using wasd keys

Tags: c, coordinates

I wanted to make simple program in C language which allows user change values of x  and y coordinates. w means y++, s means y--, a means x--, d means x++. The code I've created already is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=0,y=0;
    char choice;

do
{
    printf("Your position x=%i y=%i\n",x,y);
    scanf("%c",&choice);
    if(choice=='w'){y++;}
    else if(choice=='s'){y--;}
    else if(choice=='a'){x--;}
    else if(choice=='d'){x++;}
    else if(choice=='q'){printf("Quit\n");}
    else {printf("Wrong\n");}
}while(choice!='q');

return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately if I execute program and for example call 'w' I  get output:

```
Your position x=0 y=0
w
Your position x=0 y=1
Wrong
Your position x=0 y=1
```

Why does the program work like this?

Comment: You need to consume the trailing newline in `scanf`, change to `scanf(" 
 %c",&choice);`, notice the space before `%c`

Comment: Your code reads a character, but you actually want it to read a line.

Comment: Wow, it's working. Can you explain why does this solution work? I can't get the point :)

Comment: When you type input and hit enter `scanf()` consumes your input but not the remaining newline, using `" %c"` the following `scanf()` in the loop consumes this remaining newline.

Comment: You might want to look into ncurses if you're on Linux.

Comment: I know it's not relevant here, but you may want to take a look at this question ALSO. [How to move cursor in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677992/how-to-move-cursor-back-to-the-first-line-in-c/35387468)

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int x=0,y=0;
char choice;
    while(scanf("%c",&choice)&& choice!='q')
    {

        if(choice=='w')
        {
            y++;
            printf("Your position x=%i y=%i\n",x,y);

        }
        else if(choice=='s')
        {
            y--;
            printf("Your position x=%i y=%i\n",x,y);

        }
        else if(choice=='a')
        {
            x--;
            printf("Your position x=%i y=%i\n",x,y);

        }
        else if(choice=='d')
        {
            x++;
            printf("Your position x=%i y=%i\n",x,y);

        }
        else if(choice=='q')
        {
            printf("Quit\n");
            printf("Your position x=%i y=%i\n",x,y);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Wrong\n");
            printf("Your position x=%i y=%i\n",x,y);

        }
        scanf("%c",&choice);
    }


  return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Keine Lust above, in order to use the output of `scanf()` in this way you must prepend the `%c` conversion with whitespace to eliminate the newline.

At your option, you may also use `switch case` instead of all those `if` statements. Compiling either one with `gcc` results in the exact same code size, but some would argue that `switch case` is slightly more readable. Taking all of the above into consideration, we would arrive at the following source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=0,y=0;
    char choice;

do
{
    printf("Your position x=%i y=%i\n",x,y);
    scanf(" %c",&choice);
    switch (choice) {
      case 'w':
        y++;
        break;
      case 's':
        y--;
        break;
      case 'a':
        x--;
        break;
      case 'd':
        x++;
        break;
      case 'q':
        printf("Quit\n");
        break;
      default:
        printf("Wrong\n");
    }
}while(choice!='q');

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this statement:

```
scanf("%c",&choice);
```

inputs the next character in `stdin`.

Most likely, that char will be 'white space', like a newline.

A suggested fix would be to modify the format string to contain a leading space. Similar to:

```
scanf(" %c",&choice);
```

That leading space will consume any leading 'white space'.